# Proof of Exact differential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative, differential

I'm thinking of proving the exact differential equation, but don't know if I understand it quite right.

Let's say we have 
$\alpha(x,y) = A(x,y) \mathrm{d}x + B(x,y)\mathrm{d}y$  and know that a function $f$ it's called exact if $\mathrm{d}F = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} \mathrm{d}x + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \mathrm{d}y$, so how do I prove that $\alpha$ is only exact if and only if $\frac{\partial A}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial B}{\partial x}$.

My idea: Let's start by some followings from this expression $\mathrm{d}F = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} \mathrm{d}x + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \mathrm{d}y$:
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{dd}F&= \frac{\partial \mathrm{d} F}{\partial x} \mathrm{d}x + \frac{\partial \mathrm{d} F}{\partial y} \mathrm{d}y = \frac{\partial^{2} F}{\partial x^{2}} \mathrm{d}x^{2} + \frac{\partial^{2}F}{\partial x \partial y}\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y +   \frac{\partial^{2}F}{\partial y \partial x} \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y +  \frac{\partial^{2}F}{\partial y^{2}} \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \frac{\partial^{2} F}{\partial x^{2}} \mathrm{d}x^{2} + 2 \frac{\partial^{2}F}{\partial x \partial y}\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y +  \frac{\partial^{2}F}{\partial y^{2}} \mathrm{d}y 
\end{align*}
Now this expression can only be equal to $\mathrm{d}\alpha$ if  $\frac{\partial A}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial B}{\partial x}$ is satisfied, because
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d} \alpha =& \frac{\partial^{2} A}{\partial x^{2}} \mathrm{d}x^{2} + \frac{\partial^{2}A}{\partial x \partial y}\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y +   \frac{\partial^{2}B}{\partial x \partial y} \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y +  \frac{\partial^{2}B}{\partial y^{2}} \mathrm{d}y  \, . 
\end{align*}
Is that correct?

Please help me solving that, because I think I'm running in circles.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here:

The first is, the claim is not true! For example, computing directly shows that $$\alpha := \frac{-y \,dx + x \,dy}{x^2 + y^2}$$ satisfies $$d\alpha = 0 ,$$ but there is so $F$ such that $\alpha = dF$. If there were, then by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for line integrals the integral of $\alpha$ along the unit circle $\Bbb S^1$ (oriented anticlockwise) would be $\oint_{\Bbb S^1} \alpha = \oint_{\Bbb S^1} dF = 0$, but parameterizing $\Bbb S^1$ and computing directly gives $\oint_{\Bbb S^1} \alpha = 2 \pi$, a contradiction.

The claim *is* true locally, however: If $d \alpha = 0$, then around any point $x$ in the domain of $\alpha$ there *is* a neighborhood $U$ and a function $F : U \to \Bbb R$ such that $\alpha\vert_U = dF$, and in fact, we can take $U$ to be any simply connected subset of the domain of $\alpha$ containing $x$.

The second problem is that there are some evident mechanical misconceptions. First, if $A \,dx + B \,dy$ is exact, we have
$$
\begin{align}
0
&= d(A \,dx + B \,dy) \\
&= dA \wedge dx + dB \wedge dy \\
&= \left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial A}{\partial y} dy\right) \wedge dx + \left(\frac{\partial B}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial B}{\partial y} dy\right) \wedge dy
\end{align}
$$
The antisymmetry of $\wedge$ gives that $dx \wedge dx = dx \wedge dy = 0$ and $dx \wedge dy = - dy \wedge dx$, so we can write the above equation as
$$0 = C(x, y) \,dx \wedge dy$$
for some function $C$ given in terms of $A$ and $B$---what is it?---and hence conclude that $C(x, y) = 0$. (Note that this computation does not depend on the domain of $A \,dx + B \,dy$, so exactness implies that $\frac{\partial A}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial B}{\partial x}$, but again, as we say above, the reverse in general requires a topological restriction.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I should say I'm not that deep in mathematics like you. I'm physician and need to do that exercise for thermodynamics. I have knowledge in complex analysis and can follow you're steps, but it went to deep for this exercise.

Comment: Setting aside the issue mentioned in the first part---which *is* an issue, by the way, as the exercise is not correct as stated!---is there some concept mentioned in the second part that you don't have available? I shouldn't think so: By definition $d(A \,dx + B \,dy)$ is a $2$-form, so one needs to have the coordinate expression for $d$ and the wedge product, $\wedge$, available. That and the fact that $\alpha \wedge \beta = -\beta \wedge \alpha$ for $1$-forms $\alpha, \beta$ are all that are used here.

Comment: Sorry you are right the original exercise was:  Show if $\alpha$ is exact, then $A(x,y)$ and $B(x,y)$ satisfy the condition $\frac{\partial A}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial B}{\partial x}$ But I don't understand why your solution is equivalent to this condition....

Comment: As I pose in my answer, what does the expression $C(x, y)$ turn out to be?

Comment: I think I got it \begin{align*}
0 &= C(x,y) \mathrm{d} x \wedge \mathrm{d}y= \frac{\partial A}{\partial y} \mathrm{d}y  \wedge \mathrm dx +   \frac{\partial B}{\partial x} \mathrm{d}x \wedge \mathrm dy   =  \frac{\partial A}{\partial y} \mathrm{d}y  \wedge \mathrm dx -  \frac{\partial B}{\partial x} \mathrm{d}y \wedge \mathrm dx \\
\Rightarrow & \frac{\partial A}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial B}{\partial x} 
\end{align*} Thanks again!!!

Comment: Yes, that's right, and you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you were nearly there at one point, then you wandered off.

If $A \text{d} x + B \text{d} y$ is exact, then, as you correctly say, $A = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $B = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ for some function $f(x,y)$.

Now just have another look at the thing you want to prove: $\frac{\partial A}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial B}{\partial x}$, and the solution should be obvious.

Comment: Ok but did I do something wrong in the calculation or should I write something more?

Comment: You wrote out the $\text{d}^2 F$ and $\text{d}\alpha$ correctly but I fail to see what you wanted to get by comparing them.
I just tried to hint at a quick solution.

Comment: No I really don't know... At wikipedia they write some conclusion [link] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential#Two_and_three_dimensions) but no explanation or derivation. I'm not seeing where I can use the assumption $\frac{\partial A}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial B}{\partial x}$